# How to change seaborn jointplot linewidth?

Tags: width, line, settings, seaborn, curve

[image]

```
hexs = sns.jointplot(a,b,marker = '.', kind = "reg", height=1.476, scatter_kws={'s':2, 'linewidth':0.1},joint_kws={'line_kws':{'linewidth':'0.5'}})
```

I can change the scatter size and the regression line width.
but how can I change the curve width ？(the curve pointed by the black arrow)

Answer (score 3):

As the name indicates, a `jointplot` is a combination of some other plots.

The visual aspect of the marginal subplots can be controlled via [`marginal_kws=`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html).
In this case, the marginal plots are drawn using [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html). On its turn, in a `distplot`, the kernel density approximation is drawn with [`kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot). The parameters of this kdeplot are controlled via the `kde_kws` inside the `marginal_kws`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, marker='.', kind="reg", height=1.476,
                  scatter_kws={'s': 2, 'linewidth': 0.1},
                  joint_kws={'line_kws': {'linewidth': 0.5}},
                  marginal_kws={'color': 'g', 'kde_kws': {'linewidth': 0.5}})
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]